# Android animation for 1 second

Tags: android

I am trying to make a page where when the user leaves the page, there will be an animation (eg.: button will slide out) in the page and after that, the user will be sendt to a different activity.

No issue with the animation, but as the code for starting the new activity is written just after the animation code, the animation is not completing for 1 second (as I have set).

I want to execute the animation for 1 second first and then move to another activity.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AnimationListener.

```
private Animation.AnimationListener animListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // write code to start new activity.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }
};
```

Assign above listener to your animation

```
animation.setAnimationListener(animListener);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, U came really fast

Answer (score 1):

```
//Startanimation
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
// call Activity
// End animation

                }
            }, 1000);
```